# Write a formula with reference to another sheet with XlsxWriter

Tags: python, xlsx, xlsxwriter

I am trying to fill some cell of my sheet with a reference to another sheet.
I have created two sheets, `mysheet` and `anothersheet`.

```
row_ref = 5
for i in range(100):
    ws_overview.write_formula(i+1, 0, '=anothersheet.'+'B{}'.format(row_ref))
    row_ref += 1
```

The problem is that when I run the Python script, it generates the `.xlsx` file, but the cell was filled with `=anothersheet.b1`. The character `b` must be in uppercase. I did try to use `upper()` from Python, but it does not work. I used `.` instead of `!` to reference a cell because I am using LibreOffice.

How can I fix the reference?

Comment: Why not format the formula as one string? `'=anothersheet.B{}'.format(row_ref)`

Comment: Also worth noting that when regularly using xlsxwriter, another sheet is referenced by quotes, e.g. `"='anothersheet'!B{}".format(row_ref)`

Comment: Thanks for your advice.I got confused due to i was making a .xlsx document and i opened it with libreoffice. i've changed the . for a ! and It's works fine.